# Make PrintWriter or OutputStreamWriter print immediately

Tags: java, io, printwriter

Is there a way to make `PrintWriter` or `OutputStreamWriter` print immediately after `.write` method is invoked? I have `autoFlush` turned on for `PrintWriter`. Yet for both these classes, the contents get printed only when the writer is closed.

For what it's worth, I am using `Writer`s because I need to abstract over console output, file output, and string output.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that shows the problem:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (read.hasNextLine()) {
            String input = read.nextLine();
            if (input.equals("end"))
                break;
            p.write(input);
        }
        p.close();
    }
}

/* Sample run: (first four lines are input)
cow
mow
pow
end
cowmowpow
*/
```

Comment: Please show a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Since it is a `Writer`, why don't you just invoke `println()` which does flush the data immediately with closing the stream?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad, because `println` is not a member of [`java.io.Writer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for the `autoFlush` constructor parameter says:

> A boolean; if true, the println, printf, or format methods will flush the output buffer

Given that you're not using any of those methods, it's not entirely surprising that it's not helping.

The simplest approach would be to just call [`flush()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#flush%28%29) manually after every `write` - that's what you're trying to achieve, after all. I don't know of anything which will make a writer flush by default after every write.

Of course, you could write your own wrapper class - the equivalent of `BufferedWriter`, but with the opposite effect. It could delegate all methods to the wrapped writer, but then immediately call `flush()` afterwards.